# KerasRegressor cannot clone object - no idea why this error is being thrown

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building a basic Keras model with a scikit learn wrapper so that I can do a random cross-val search to optimize the parameters. The code is the following:

```
def build_model(n_hidden=1, n_neurons=30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=[8]):
     model = models.Sequential()
     model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
     for layer in range(n_hidden):
          model.add(layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
     model.add(layers.Dense(1))
     optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate)
     model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
     return model

keras_reg = wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model)
keras_reg.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks= 
              [callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
mse_test = keras_reg.score(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = keras_reg.predict(X_new)

from scipy.stats import reciprocal
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "n_neurons": (np.arange(1,100)),
    "learning_rate": (reciprocal(3e-4, 3e-2))
}

rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks= 
                 [callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

I am getting the error on the last line:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ml_hyperparams.py", line 49, in 
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])

File "C:\Users\Jesus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py", line 736, in fit
**self.best_params_))
File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 82, in clone
(estimator, name))

RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor object at 0x0000015C3CBCDB88>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter learning_rate

I read somewhere that this usually occurs when the params dict has nested list and that it can be fixed using tuples hence the parentheses, but obviously that doesn't work. What is most unusual about this is that I am copying this code verbatim from Aurélien Géron's - "Hands-On Machine Learning" textbook so I have no idea why this error is being thrown. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tipically folks says to work with list and tuple instead of numpy array, but unfortunately it doesn't fully solve the problem. This an issue ([here](http://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13586), and [here](http://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15722)) in Kera's scikit learn wrapper, which can be easily solved in the following way:

1. Find your tensorflow's folder installation and the file *tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py*
2. Edit the file in the line 117:

remove: `res = copy.deepcopy(self.sk_params)`

add:  `res = self.sk_params.copy()`

It basically switch from a deep copy to a shalow one. It worked fine here. The original [solution is here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/41341/files) (a [pull merged](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/41341) in Tensorflow's project)

Best regards